# Issues redirecting standard output to a file in bash

Tags: bash, file-io

I've written a short bash script to update some twitter_ebooks bots. The commands involved generate a lot of output and I want to redirect it to a file with the day's date. I tried using the top aswer to [this question on ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file) however the vast majority of the output still goes to the terminal.

My bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

arc() { ## $1 is account name $2 is log file
    ebooks archive $1 corpus/$1.json >> "$2"
    ebooks consume corpus/$1.json >> "$2"
}

accounts=(some twitter names)

echo "moving to ~/twitter/snare_ebooks"
cd ~/twitter/snare_ebooks

date_var=$(date -d @$(date +%s) +"%m_%d_%Y")
logfile=~/ebooks_archive_logs/$date_var.log
touch "${logfile}"
echo "model update log for $date_var" >> "${logfile}"

echo "archiving and consuming the corpus"

for accountName in ${accounts[*]}
do
    arc $accountName "${logfile}"
done

echo "git adding"
git add --all . >> "${logfile}"

echo "git committing"
git commit -m "model update" >> "${logfile}"

echo "pushing to heroku"
git push heroku master >> "${logfile}"
```

The log file that is created only contains:

```
model update log for 07_28_2015
[master 2eb0961] model update
 4 files changed, 134 insertions(+), 134 deletions(-)
```

Can anyone explain why this isn't working as expected? Also what needs to be done in order for it to work as expected?

Comment: The `-d @$(date +%s)` is unnecessary; you're just telling `date` to use the current time (which is the default).

Comment: Also, you may need to redirect standard error as well as standard output, depending on what the various programs use and what, exactly, you want in the log.

Comment: `arc "$accountname" >> "$logfile"` is better than doing the redirection in the function twice. Similarly doing the redirection *once* on the entire contents of the script would be even better.

Comment: What output is showing up on the terminal instead of going to the logfile?

Comment: @chepner I redirected standard error with `&>>` and it worked like a charm! If you write an answer I'd love to mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of redirecting every command, you can do this at the beginning of the script:

```
date_var=$(date -d @$(date +%s) +"%m_%d_%Y")
logfile=~/ebooks_archive_logs/$date_var.log
exec >"$logfile" 2>&1
```

`exec` with no command and just redirection operators simply changes the I/O connections for the remainder of the script. `2>&1` additionally redirects standard error. If you were seeing output, those commands were probably writing it to `stderr` instead of `stdout`.

If you want to be able to occasionally write to the original `sdtdout`, like your `echo "git adding"` lines, you could do:

```
exec 3>&1 >"$logfile" 2>&1
```

This moves the original `stdout` to FD 3, and then you can do:

```
echo "git adding" >&3
```

It's possible that some of the commands were writing to `/dev/tty` instead of `stdout`, but this is unlikely (this is generally only done for things like prompts for input).

Comment: One tiny issue with the global redirect: there is one `echo` statement in the script that wasn't originally redirected (but that might have been an oversight).

Comment: Actually, I now see that there are a bunch of `echo` statements that are used for showing the step of the script. It's not clear whether he wants those in the log or not, and maybe they were just temporary.

Comment: The undirected `echo` statements are intentional, I want to have a general idea of where the script is at in its execution

Comment: @WillNorvelle I updated my answer to show how to deal with exceptions.

Comment: @Barmar this works and makes my script much cleaner, thanks